# Kotlin Data Class enforce value constraints

Tags: validation, kotlin, data-class

Is there any way in kotlin to have constraints on a **data** classes values. I'm looking for something similar to the following java. It doesn't need to be an illegal argument exception, and the constraints aren't necessarily on String fields.

```
public class TotallyMadeUpClass{
    private String username
    public String getUsername(){ return this.username }

    //Constrain the value somehow.
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        if (username.length > 10)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException()
        this.username = username}
}
```

Or this example which is even closer to what I'm trying to achieve.

```
public class TotallyMadeUpClass{
    private final String username;

    TotallyMadeUpClass(String username, OtherParams others){
        if (username.length > 10)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException()
        this.username = username
    }

    public String getUsername(){ return this.username }


}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More idiomatic way to apply constrains in Kotlin is to use [`require`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/require.html) function:

```
data class TotallyMadeUpClass(val username: String) {
    init {
        require(username.length > 10) { "Length must be greater than 10" }
        // ...
    }
}
```

It throws an **IllegalArgumentException** if the value is **false**.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an init block like this:

```
data class Cow(val hasMilk: Boolean) {
    init {
        if (!hasMilk) {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Cows must have milk")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using [`require()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/require.html) is a marginally simpler and more idiomatic way of doing that.